# Can't set custom paper size through CSS

Tags: javascript, css

I try to set up my custom paper size before printing in a browser. Here is my simple example:

```js
window.print();
```

```css
body {
margin:0;
}
div {
width:210mm;
height:50mm;
border:1px solid #000;
}
@media print {
  @page {
    size:210mm 50mm;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

As the div has 210mm it should be stretched the entire width of the paper but it doesn't (at least in my Chrome's print window with "Microsoft Print to PDF" printer). So as I can understand, I still have standard A4 paper, just landscape.

How to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Add `margin: 0;` in the `@page` selector.

(I also changed the style of the `div` so that the border is included in the size.)

Note: This is not possible with actual printers. It only works with the "Print to PDF" or similar option. Tested in Chrome 77.

```js
window.print();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  width: 210mm;
  height: 50mm;
  border: 10px solid #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 8px;
}

@media print {
  @page {
    size: 210mm 50mm;
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <b>Lorem Ipsum</b> is simply dummy text of the printing and
  typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
  standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an
  unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled
  it to make a type specimen book.
</div>
```

Comment: Now again I have A4, just landscape

Comment: I changed some things. Does it work now using the "Save as PDF" printer? If not, can you clarify what you want the output to be, preferably with a picture of what you are currently getting.

Comment: Yes, as well as your previous code. I didn't know there is such difference between "Microsoft Print to PDF" and "Save as PDF"

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
@page {
  size: 210mm 70mm;
  margin: 1;
}
```

```js
window.print();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  width: 210mm;
  height: 50mm;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

@media print {
  @page {
    size: 210mm 70mm;
    margin: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Now I have portrait A4

Comment: so you want page same size as div?

Comment: Yes, it may be the same as the height of the div